# Prevent multiple callback error when client send multiple requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, async-await

I am building my first web application with node v12.18.1 and express v4.17.1. Since the start of development, I have the same error on all routes: when i quickly click a link multiple times the server crashes with this error: [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CV9j.png). It can be fixed in the front-end by disabling events on user input after a click, but I prefer to know what is wrong with my code.

Route of the index page :

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let controller_index = require("../controller/controller_index.js")

router.get('/', controller_index.get_index);

router.get('/rubrique/:category', controller_index.get_category);

module.exports = router;
```

Controller of the index page :

```
const Query = require("../lib/dbs.js");
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
const utils = require('../lib/utils');

exports.get_index = async (req, res, next) => {

  try {

    let user = await Query.findOne("users", "_id", ObjectId(req.user_id));

    let notification;

    if (user) {

      notification = await Query.findSortToArray("notifications", "for_user", ObjectId(user._id));

      notification.count = notification.filter((notif => !notif.hasOwnProperty("readedAt"))).length;

    }

    if (!req.query.q) {

      let page = req.query.page > 1 ? (req.query.page * 10) - 10 : req.query.page <= 0 ? undefined : 0;

      let current_page = req.query.page ? Number(req.query.page) : 1;

      let [countDocuments, docs] = await Promise.all([Query.countAll("articles"), Query.findAll(page)]);

      let nb_pages = Math.ceil(countDocuments / 10);

      if (!docs.length && current_page !== 1) {

        next();

      }

      else {

        docs = await documents_processing(docs, user, req);

        res.render("../views/index.pug", { docs: docs, user: user, notification: notification, nb_pages: nb_pages, current_page: current_page })

      };

    }

    else if (req.query.q) {

      let page = req.query.page > 1 ? (req.query.page * 10) - 10 : req.query.page <= 0 ? undefined : 0;

      let current_page = req.query.page ? Number(req.query.page) : 1;

      let [countDocuments, docs] = await Promise.all([Query.countAllBySearch("articles", req.query.q), Query.findAllBySearch(req.query.q, page)]);

      let nb_pages = Math.ceil(countDocuments / 10);

      if (!docs.length && current_page !== 1) {

        next();

      }

      else {

        docs = await documents_processing(docs, user, req);

        res.render("../views/index.pug", { docs: docs, search: req.query.q, user: user, notification: notification, nb_pages: nb_pages, current_page: current_page })

      };

    };

  }

  catch (err) {

    console.error(err);

    return next(err);
  };

};
```

Example of static function of the query object :

```
const connect = require("../index.js")

module.exports = class Query {

    static async findOne(collection, field, item) {
        const result = await connect.client.db("blog_db").collection(collection).findOne({ [`${field}`]: item })
        return result;
    };

    static async findOneAndUpdateOrInsertOnUser(collection, field, itemToSearch, updateItem) {
        const result = await connect.client.db("blog_db").collection(collection).findOneAndUpdate({ [`${field}`]: itemToSearch }, { $set: updateItem }, { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false });
        return result;
    };

    static async findSortToArray(collection, field, item) {
        const results = await connect.client.db("blog_db").collection(collection).find({ [`${field}`]: item }).sort({ date: -1 }).toArray()
        return results;
    };

};
```

I'm fairly new to programming so any advice is welcome, thank you in advance!

----- EDIT -----

Kind of solution :

I have found people who have talked about this error on node v12 and newer, with a downgrade to v10 the issue was resolved without any clear explanation yet.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the screenshot you've shared shows that the error is "Callback called multiple times", but I don't see anywhere obvious in the code you've shared where this is happening. As you're saying this bug only happens when multiple requests are made rapidly one after the other, it suggests there might be a global variable which is being shared between requests, which is something that should be avoided.

To debug the error you're seeing I would recommend commenting out all of the code in the `get_index` function and gradually uncommenting it in small chunks until you see the error happen again. You will probably want to do the same with the code that is called by the `get_index` controller function e.g. `documents_processing`, as the issue might possibly lie there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your method, but with a single instruction of any type the issue reappear. I have found a solution for now with a downgrade to v10.

Answer (score 0):

Express only support callback-style, and you're using async function to handle the logic.

Basically, with async function, you call a function without waiting for it to resolve the logics. Hence, it creates too many callbacks in the event loop when that route has a large amount of concurrent coming requests.

```js
function asyncWrapper(fn) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    return Promise.resolve(fn(req))
      .then((result) => res.send(result))
      .catch((err) => next(err))
  }
};

router.get('/', asyncWrapper(controller_index.get_index));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I wrapped my controller with your function but i see no noticeable effect. I have found people who have discussed this error with node v12 and newer. With a downgrade to v10, the error disappeared for no reason but it's better than nothing.